# android - last added item to layout is strech vertical. WHY? (Remake)

Tags: android, layout, fill

**[Second Edited]**

**I found where problem is**. But i dont know why its doing. It cant be margin on LinearLayout (or just marginLeft). Does anybody know why it cant have ?

***[EDITED]***

**Hello** i have xml file in layout like bellow.And iam adding TextViews from any xml layout to horizontal LinearLayout. This layout structure is given and i cant change it. 
And last added TextView is streching always verticaly. I dont know why i am in tottaly despair. Too many hours i was try* that but without no idea. I know just its not in programicaly adding TextViews ..
If some body know why its doing i will be thankful.

```
<RelativeLayout 

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/back_border"
>

<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/manager_view_table_header"  
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>  


    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout_for_textViews"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
    android:layout_margin="6px"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/back_border"
    >
      <!--  horizontal layout,    HERE IAM ADDING TEXTVIEWS  -->

    </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>

<!--What is here its no important
     because, there is RelativeLayout with alignBellow relative layout before  -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

and TextView witch iam addig to LinearLayout:

```
<TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="7px"
        android:paddingLeft="7px"
        android:paddingTop="3px"
        android:paddingBottom="3px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"    
        android:background="@drawable/background_table"
        android:textColor="#330033"
        android:text="Some text"
        />
```

Comment: Why do you have three enclosed layouts?

Comment: What ListView are you talking about? I don't see one in the xml you posted.

Comment: Sory .. no ListView but TextView .. They are enclosed because its only  part of my main xml. Other things are not important i mean . Sory for my bad formuled question. I go rewrite it .. see post above

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace the android:layout_margin="6px" from the LinearLayout by android:padding="6px".
I think this will solve your problem. I mean the new LInearLayout should be like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/layout_for_textViews"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
android:padding="6px"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="#44ff435f"
>
```

Comment: Yes, its doing just marginLeft, Its coming unlogic than just last item its streched, maby because that textView has marginLeft, but still question is WHY ?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with your three layouts. Wat's the porpose of all thses nested layouts, try to recreate the text views with a single relative layout, and use the android:layout_above and android:layout_below for placing the text views.

Comment: In, and around this three layouts its other views, that are not important, sory for my bad formuled question i rewrite it to better.

Comment: i have changed linear layout to relative layout but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to refactor this code.

You might want to use actual `ListView` to create repeated elements.

and why is `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` declared thrice in this xml code, when it is actually required just once at top root element.

Even with this layout to solve your problem, if other things are not working  a nice idea would be to switch to Graphic layout(bottom tab in eclipse when on .xml file) and manually try to set the third `TextView` **(not listview)** height manually, you can observe the changes then and finalize them accordingly..

Comment: Sory i cant refactor this code.. I edited it to more understand post :p .. sry pls check it yet.

Comment: I am using netbeans, but i go find something to show it on graphic layout